# Java rsa decrypt_mode behavior

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I was just experimenting with the following code but I don't understand why the code behaves the way it does:

```
public class Test
{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory1 = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate certificate1 = (X509Certificate)certificateFactory1.generateCertificate(Test.class.getResourceAsStream("pub.cer");      //Loading ssl certificate 
        PublicKey pk1 = certificate1.getPublicKey();
        Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NOPADDING");
        cipher1.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk1);
        bytes[] encrypted = cipher1.doFinal("dummy".getBytes("UTF-8");

        CertificateFactory certificateFactory2 = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate certificate2 = (X509Certificate)certificateFactory2.generateCertificate(Test.class.getResourceAsStream("pub.cer");     //Loading ssl certificate
        PublicKey pk2 = certificate2.getPublicKey();
        Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NOPADDING");
        cipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pk2);
        bytes[] decrypted = cipher2.doFinal(encrypted);
    }
}
```

Why in `byte[]` decrypted I'm getting output by `doFinal`? I'm using jdk1.8.0_192.

Because I'm using public key for decryption and in asymmetric public key cryptography we can encrypt with public key and decrypt with private key.

Can somebody explain that and hopefully back it up with documentation?

Comment: Your example doesn't even compile. Please don't type in code, instead copy&paste.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, I get an exception every time. Please try to produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise I doubt we'll be able to help you.

Comment: You can test this with a self signed certificate

Comment: I did test it with a self-signed certificate. Again, please produce an MCVE.

Comment: Can you share the results? Did you get runtime exception again? I'm just executing the above code and getting the output in byte[] decrypted

Comment: Yes, I get a `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error` every time. I should point out that I tested this with the current adoptopenjdk JDK 8 on a macbook pro.

Comment: I'm executing this code on eclipse on Windows 10 with Java jdk8 not openjdk and in byte[] decrypted, i'm getting 256 bytes of data. The key is 2048 bit rsa key in ssl certificate.

Comment: My apologies, it's NOPADDING instead of PKCS1PADDING. I have edited the question

Comment: Please re-read my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify `NoPadding` then you basically get modular exponentiation. Of course, before that there is a step to convert the binary input to a number, and afterwards the encoding from a number to binary again. Funny enough that's true for both encryption and decryption, as those operations are rather symmetric for RSA.

The only difference is that you do first use the public key for encryption and the *private key* for decryption. However, sometimes you have to create your own *verification* scheme. In that case a raw modular exponentiation *with the public key* will nicely give you the (commonly padded) result. So then *decryption* with the public key makes some sense, even if it technically shouldn't be called decryption.

All in all, if your input is about the right size than just the decoding the input to a number, modular encryption (or decryption) and finally encoding the result will *never* fail. So you just get an output with the same size as the modulus, i.e. the key size in bytes. It is the unpadding for RSA that may fail. But your code would just run because you don't do any unpadding.

Of course, if you use the wrong modulus and exponent, the result of the decryption will not make any sense; it will look like a random number between 0 and the modulus used for the last operation.

Comment: @ Maarten Bodewes, thanks for that nice explanation

Comment: Note 'naive' RSA -- only the modular exponentiation as in the 1977 CACM paper -- was found to be insecure and replaced by the padded versions, where signing is truly different from encryption, about 30 years ago. Even PKCS1-padded encryption is not fully safe and was improved by OAEP 20 years ago; google 'Bleichenbacher attack'. There are _many_ Qs about this on crypto.SX and security.SX.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#init(int,%20java.security.Key)

> Throws:
>       InvalidKeyException - if the given key is inappropriate for initializing this cipher, or requires algorithm parameters that cannot be determined from the given key, or if the given key has a keysize that exceeds the maximum allowable keysize (as determined from the configured jurisdiction policy files).

RSA in decrypt mode reqruires PrivateKey instance instead of PublicKey and hence Case 2 of the above example would throw this exception.

If you are wondering Why it does not produce Compile time error, PublicKey and PrivateKey both extends Key Class and hence the Cipher.init(int,Key) signature is satisfied by both the Cases of your code.

Comment: Initially I also thought the same that this code will generate exception but in actual I got output in byte[] decrypted, which looks like java again encrypted the input data

Comment: The SunJCE Cipher instance for RSA is an exception; due to the widely mistaken belief in early years that "RSA signature is just encryption backwards", it accepts ENCRYPT_MODE with RSAPrivateKey and DECRYPT_MODE with RSAPublicKey and actually does PKCS1v1.5 **signature**, either with 'block type 1' padding or none as Maarten says, and not encryption at all. See e.g. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/69c4f673b33e/src/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/RSACipher.java